# Specifying an integer within the maximum of an unsigned 64-bit integer does **not** cause a buffer overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, exploit-development

The program I am working with has a POC published for it, but not a full explanation. I have been told by my mentor (I am part of a research program) to disclose as little information as possible about the exploit.

The program is ran on Kali Rolling x86_64. The exploit involves performing a buffer underflow while using memcpy. The number wraps around to 18446744073709551208, which is the maximum value of an unsigned 64-bit integer (2^64 - 408). This number does not work; however, supplying a much smaller or bigger number such as 99999 or 18446744073709***9***51208 does work.

Although I can not demonstrate the exact code, I can provide an example of what I am experiencing below.

```
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char a[40000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40000; i++) {
        a[i] = 'A';
    }
    char b[20000];

    memcpy(&b, &a, 18446744073709551208);
}
```

Compiling the code with the following:

`gcc main.c -O0 -g3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o main`

And running gef with a breakpoint at the end of the code:

`gdb -ex 'break main.c:12' --args ./main`

Produces the following:

```
Starting program: redacted_path/main 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:12
12      }
[ Legend: Modified register | Code | Heap | Stack | String ]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── registers ────
$rax   : 0x0               
$rbx   : 0x00007fffffffde98  →  0x00007fffffffe1f3  →  "redacted_path"
$rcx   : 0x00007ffffffef060  →  0x0000000000000000
$rdx   : 0xfffffffffffffe68
$rsp   : 0x00007ffffffef310  →  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
$rbp   : 0x1               
$rsi   : 0x00007fffffff3e80  →  0x0000000000000000
$rdi   : 0x00007ffffffef310  →  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
$rip   : 0x0000555555555195  →  <main+92> add rsp, 0xea78
$r8    : 0x0               
$r9    : 0x00007ffff7fcf6a0  →  <_dl_fini+0> push rbp
$r10   : 0x00007ffff7dd89d8  →  0x0010001a00001b50
$r11   : 0x00007ffff7f23a00  →  <__memmove_evex_unaligned_erms+0> mov rax, rdi
$r12   : 0x0               
$r13   : 0x00007fffffffdea8  →  0x00007fffffffe220  →  "COLORFGBG=15;0"
$r14   : 0x0000555555557dd8  →  0x00005555555550f0  →  <__do_global_dtors_aux+0> endbr64 
$r15   : 0x00007ffff7ffd020  →  0x00007ffff7ffe2e0  →  0x0000555555554000  →   jg 0x555555554047
$eflags: [zero carry parity adjust sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow resume virtualx86 identification]
$cs: 0x33 $ss: 0x2b $ds: 0x00 $es: 0x00 $fs: 0x00 $gs: 0x00 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── stack ────
0x00007ffffffef310│+0x0000: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"    ← $rsp, $rdi
0x00007ffffffef318│+0x0008: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef320│+0x0010: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef328│+0x0018: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef330│+0x0020: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef338│+0x0028: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef340│+0x0030: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
0x00007ffffffef348│+0x0038: "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA[...]"
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── code:x86:64 ────
   0x555555555188 <main+79>        mov    rdi, rax
   0x55555555518b <main+82>        call   0x555555555030 <memcpy@plt>
   0x555555555190 <main+87>        mov    eax, 0x0
 → 0x555555555195 <main+92>        add    rsp, 0xea78
   0x55555555519c <main+99>        ret    
   0x55555555519d                  add    BYTE PTR [rax], al
   0x55555555519f                  add    BYTE PTR [rax-0x7d], cl
   0x5555555551a2 <_fini+2>        in     al, dx
   0x5555555551a3 <_fini+3>        or     BYTE PTR [rax-0x7d], cl
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── source:main.c+12 ────
      7          a[i] = 'A';
      8      }
      9      char b[20000];
     10  
     11      memcpy(&b, &a, 18446744073709551208);
●→   12  }
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── threads ────
[#0] Id 1, Name: "main", stopped 0x555555555195 in main (), reason: BREAKPOINT
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── trace ────
[#0] 0x555555555195 → main()
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
gef➤  p a
$1 = 'A' <repeats 40000 times>
gef➤  p b
$2 = 'A' <repeats 128 times>, '\000' <repeats 19871 times>
```

Why does this issue occur? What is the significance of the number being close to the maximum value of an unsigned 64-bit integer?

Comment: If possibly the vulnerable call is a `memmove` or equivalent code that does some pointer arithmetic to decide the ordering of the copy, overflow in that check might fool that branch.  The ordering chosen might be critical to getting the copy to overwrite the loop variable (and exit the loop) before running off the page and causing an access violation.  In your backtrace, one of the symbols is `__memmove_evex_unaligned_erms`.  I would definitely make it a goal to see whether "working" and "failing" exploits differ in the copy ordering.